# Irreducibly of $x^5-x-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Using the affine linearized polynomial $f(x)=x^p-x-b$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_q$ if and only if $\operatorname{Tr}_{\mathbb{F}_q/\mathbb{F}_p} \neq 0$. But here $\mathbb{F}_3$ is not a field extension of $\mathbb{F}_5$.

Also we have that: Let $a \in \mathbb{F}_q$ and let $p$ be the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then
the trinomial $x^P - x - a$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ if and only if it has no root in $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: If the issue is the specific instance, then you can just test it against the three monic irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ in $\Bbb F_3[x]$. (plus the roots, of course)

Comment: Actually I want to show that it is a primitive polynomial, so first I need to show that it is irreducible. 
One more think, what if it factors to polynomial of degree 1 and 4?

Comment: Obviously, one looks for roots first.

Comment: Maybe useful
$$
x^5-x=x(x+1)(x+2)(x^2+1)
$$

Answer (score 3):

Easy to see that our polynomial has no roots from $\{1,-1,0\}$ and since
$x^2+1,$ $x^2+x-1$ and $x^2-x-1$ they are unique irreducible polynomials with degree $2$, it remains an easy checking.

Comment: This is ok (+1). It can be compressed further (see my answer) by using the facts that $x^2+1\mid x^4-1$ and $(x^2+x-1)(x^2-x-1)=x^4+1$. You are welcome to take the view that my answer is roughly equivalent to proving that an integer is not divisible by either of two double digit primes by showing that it has no common factors with their product. Not much there :-)

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way of proving irreducibility of $p(x)=x^5-x-1$ in $\Bbb{F}_3[x]$ that I can think of is the following.

1. Everybody started out by checking that $p(x)$ has no roots in $\Bbb{F}_3$ and therefore no linear factors.
2. Similarly quadratic factors can be ruled by checking that $p(x)$ has no roots in $\Bbb{F}_9$. All the non-zero elements of the field of nine elements are zeros of $x^8-1=(x^4-1)(x^4+1)$. If $\beta\in \Bbb{F}_9$ is a zero of $x^4+1$, then $\beta^4=-1$. Hence $\beta^5=-\beta$ and
   $$p(\beta)=\beta^5-\beta-1=-2\beta-1.$$ For this to be equal to zero $\beta$ would have to an element of the prime field. But that possibility was ruled out in step 1 already. OTOH, if $\beta$ is a zero of $x^4-1$ then $\beta^4=1$. Consequently $\beta^5=\beta$ and
   $$p(\beta)=\beta^5-\beta-1=-1\neq0.$$
3. If a degree five polynomial is not irreducible, then it has at least one at most quadratic factor. We saw that $p(x)$ does not have such factors so it must be irreducible.

Comment: +1 and Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

$x^5-x-1$ is indeed irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$, because it has no root and no quadratic factor.

Concerning primitivity, a counting shows that there are $\frac{\phi(3^5-1)}{5}=22$ monic primitive polynomials of degree $5$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$, and $\frac{3^5-3}{5}=48$ monic irreducible polynomials of degree $5$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$. Taking out the obvious non-primitive ones, the chances are good for $x^5-x-1$ to be primitive.