# Determine whether a polynomial is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Consider the polynomial $P=X^5-X-1\in\Bbb{F}_3[X]$. I want to show that $P$ is irreducible. We can easily check it has no roots, so the only way it could not be irreducible is by being a product of two polynomials of degree $2$ and $3$ respectively. So I determine all the irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ in $\Bbb{F}_3[X]$. These are $$X^2+1;{~~} X^2+X-1 {~~}\text{and}{~~}X^2-X-1.$$
Finally I check using the Euclidean division algorithm that none of those polynomials divides $P$, which concludes the proof.

My question is this:  is there a more efficient way to do this? I had to first determine *all* the polynomials of a given degree ($2$) and then apply Euclidean algorithm to each of them. That is quite some work, and we're still considering polynomials of relatively small degree, and fields of small cardinal. I can't imagine applying the same reasoning to determine whether $Q=X^9-X^2-1\in\Bbb{F}_{17}[X]$ is irreducible.

So, is there a more efficient method to determine irreducibility, at least in the case of polynomials of small degree over small fields?

Comment: What about $X^2+2$ etc.?   Or did you mean $\mathbb F_2$?

Comment: I believe @matboy meant all *irreducible* polynomials of degree 2 or 3, because $X^2+2 \cong X^2 - 1 = (X-1)(X+1)$.

Comment: $X^2+2=X^2-1$ is not irreducible.

Comment: I meant irreducible polynomials, I edited the question.

Comment: You could use a factoring algorithm such as Berlekamp's.

Comment: Over $\Bbb{F}_p$ we have that $x^{p^2}-x$ is the product of all irreducible linear and quadratic polynomials. As $x^9-x=x(x^8-1)$ all you need to do is to check that it has no common factors with $x^8-1$. Then it won't have any quadratic factors either. That will settle the matter for a quintic.

Comment: You can check that $x^8-1$ is $(x+1)(x-1)$ times the product of the irreducible quadratics you found.

Comment: P = X^5 - X - 1 ís reducible. Just drawing a graph shows that P has a root at 1.1673039782614.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2597990/11619) for the first specific polynomial

Comment: @JonasDeSchouwer That root does not belong to the field $\Bbb{F}_3$, so it is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

I post this to give this question an answer. The idea has already been stated by Jyrki Lahtonen as a comment.

After the root check, it suffices to see that $P$ does not have an irreducible factor of degree $2$. Such a factor would also be a divisor of $X^9 - X$, as $X^{q^n} - X$ is the product of all irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_q$ whose degree divides $n$.

So you can finish your exercise in a faster way by computing $\gcd(P,X^9-X) = 1$ with the Euclidean algorithm.

The process can still be optimized a bit.

- As $X^9 - X = X(X^8 - 1)$, it suffices to compute $\gcd(P,X^8 - 1)$.
- As a little bonus over the comment of Jyrki Lahtonen, let us discuss this extra optimization if you knowing the theory of cyclotomic polynomials. Let $\Phi_n$ be the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial. We have the factorization $X^8 - 1 = \Phi_8 \Phi_4 \Phi_2 \Phi_1$. The degrees are $\deg\Phi_8 = 4$, $\deg\Phi_4 = 2$, $\deg\Phi_2 = \deg\Phi_1 = 1$ (in general, $\deg\Phi_n$ is the Euler Phi-function of $n$). So an irreducible factor of $X^8 - 1$ divides either $\Phi_8 = X^4 + 1$ or $\Phi_4 = X^2 + 1$. So it suffices to compute
  $$
  \gcd(P,X^4 + 1)\quad\text{and}\quad\gcd(P,X^2+1)\text{.}
  $$